# Should I tell my opponent about a jump they don't see?

Tags: checkers

In checkers If I see my opponent can make a jump and they don't see the jump should I tell them?  What if I have a plan for after they make the jump and they don't take it. That spoils my plan.

Answer (score 10):

It depends on if you are playing with mandatory capture rules or not. If you are playing with mandatory capture and they make a move instead of capturing a piece then you should tell them because they would be required to make the capture instead of another move. If you are not playing with mandatory capture then it doesn't matter but you can still tell them if you chose to.

Answer (score -1):

If a Jump is available and the opponent doesn't see it, You have the CHOICE of forcing the jump or taking the checker for not jumping.

Comment: Can you provide some sources to losing a piece if the player does not take the mandatory jump?

Comment: @JoeW This is a somewhat common variant known as [the huffing rule.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huff_%28board_games%29) The answer should mention the fact that this variation is in effect, but if it is then this would be the proper way to go about it.

Comment: This is the rule I know and admittedly the first I've heard of any other way. It is also the official rule described here: https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/Checkers.PDF